# very long "connecting" in chrome using ipv6

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ipv6, haproxy

A connection to an ipv6 subdobain www6.example.com takes very long. In chrome the net tab shows 20s spend in "connecting". All other times are much faster.

However only the first two connections are slow (sometimes 21s, 41s, 24s). The following requests are way below 1s. Waiting for ~2 minutes the first 2 requests are again damn slow.

Calling the same server (at the same time) via an ipv4 subdomain www.example.com is reasonably fast.

Calling other servers (at the same time) via ipv6 is also reasonably fast.

On the server is running ubuntu precise with haproxy. Most of the traffic handled is ipv4.

What is the problem on server side to have such a long time until the connection is established?

I am happy for any insights and keen to provide additional information.

[image]

edit: added screenshot from chrome.

Comment: Do you know if it's the DNS resolution, the first TCP handshake, or receiving the reply that is the problem?

Comment: Have you been able to time the DNS replies for the AAAA record?

Comment: Is your IPv6 connectivity working properly? What is the actual domain name?

Comment: Added a screenshot from chromes net tab. I assume it is the TCP handshake. The actual domain name is www6.plista.com I assume my connectivity is fine, because there is no such issue with other ipv6 native domains. Also interesting: most of the times it is a connecting time around 21s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I resolve your domain name, I get back three different AAAA records:

```
www6.plista.com.        1800    IN      AAAA    2a01:4f8:160:5102::2
www6.plista.com.        1800    IN      AAAA    2a01:4f8:151:5021::2
www6.plista.com.        1800    IN      AAAA    2a01:4f8:191:8075::2
```

I can only reach one of those IP addresses (`2a01:4f8:160:5102::2`). When I try to connect to the other two, the connection just hangs.

[21 seconds](http://youtube.com/watch?v=Ftoy2tp4kDM#t=5m22) is the timeout which Windows will use before falling back from IPv6 to IPv4. It is plausible that the same timeout applies to switching from the first IPv6 address to the next IPv6 address, when the domain name has no IPv4 address at all.

41 seconds is approximately twice as much, which sounds like what you would expect in case the browser has to try all three addresses.

Comment: yes, there was the v6 gateway missing on 2 of the 3 proxies in dns round robin. thank you very much!